# how do i create Periods and weeks (think business reports) using 2 date ranges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Basically `Fromdate` is every Sunday and `ToDate` is every saturday, i need to programatically create the `PERIOD` column on the fly through a stored procedure where period is the month and week is the week of that month,

```
--but there shouldnt be 5 weeks in a period.
FromDate    ToDate      PERIOD
2015-11-29  2015-12-05  P12-WK1 <-- see how it goes to the next period
2015-11-22  2015-11-28  P11-WK4
2015-11-15  2015-11-21  P11-WK3
2015-11-08  2015-11-14  P11-WK2
2015-11-01  2015-11-07  P11-WK1
```

I tried using the code below but my results are slightly off,

for example

`2016-01-17  2016-01-23  P1-WK4` should be

`2016-01-17  2016-01-23  P1-WK3` (notice the `WK`)

```
CASE datediff(week, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate), 0), dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate) + 1
WHEN 5 THEN 'P' + CAST(DATEPART(M, dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate + 1)AS varchar(20)) + '-WK'+ CAST(datediff(week, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate), 0), dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate)  AS varchar(20))
WHEN 6 THEN 'P' + CAST(DATEPART(M, dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate + 2)AS varchar(20)) + '-WK'+ CAST(datediff(week, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate), 0), dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate) - 4 AS varchar(20))
ELSE        'P' + CAST(DATEPART(M, dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate)AS varchar(20)) + '-WK'+ CAST(datediff(week, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate), 0), dbo.GP_MASTER.FromDate) + 1 AS varchar(20))
END AS PERIOD

2016-02-21  2016-02-27  P2-WK4
2016-02-14  2016-02-20  P2-WK3
2016-02-07  2016-02-13  P2-WK2
2016-01-31  2016-02-06  P2-WK1
2016-01-24  2016-01-30  P1-WK4
2016-01-17  2016-01-23  P1-WK4
2016-01-10  2016-01-16  P1-WK3
2016-01-03  2016-01-09  P1-WK2
```

This is my desired results

```
FromDate    ToDate      PERIOD (Period# - Week#)
2016-02-21  2016-02-27  P2-WK4
2016-02-14  2016-02-20  P2-WK3
2016-02-07  2016-02-13  P2-WK2
2016-01-31  2016-02-06  P2-WK1
2016-01-24  2016-01-30  P1-WK4
2016-01-17  2016-01-23  P1-WK3
2016-01-10  2016-01-16  P1-WK2
2016-01-03  2016-01-09  P1-WK1
```

Comment: I would create a calendar table for this.  Create a table with a date and then what period it falls within.  Then join this table ToDate on the Calendar table Date and use the period value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a Calendar Table that you can use for decades to come.  You create it once and use if for almost forever.

Examples:

Aaron Bertrand's [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Himanshu Sharma & Mohammad Nizamuddin in TechNet [T-SQL: Calendar Table](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22776.t-sql-calendar-table.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links but you posted the same URL twice.

Comment: Oops.  Corrected the second link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the period column.

```
    SELECT t.ToDate,
    'P' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),MONTH(t.ToDate)) + '-WK' + CONVERT(varchar(55),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(t.ToDate),YEAR(t.ToDate) ORDER BY t.ToDate ASC)) AS Period
    FROM MyTable AS t
    ORDER BY t.ToDate ASC
```